# expect div values are equal to the loops

Tags: cypress

I have 3 error message in a form 'error1', 'erro2', 'error3':

```
cy.get('div.el-form-item__error').invoke('text').then(($error) => {
  expect($error.trim()).to.eq('error1')
})
```

How can I expect the 3 error is matched?

If I do this:

```
cy.get('div.el-form-item__error').should("have.text", "error1")
```

I get this:

```
Error:    AssertionError: expected '[ <div.el-form-item__error>, 2 more... ]' to have text 'message', but the text was '\n          error1.\n        \n          error2.\n        \n          erro3.\n
```

Comment: why dont you use ```cy.get(selector).should("have.text", message)```? instead of ```.invoke.the(...expect)

Comment: and these error1,2,3, are they the text inside ```div.el-form-item__error``` ?

Comment: Yes <div>error1</div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, i cannot test it, may be it work from the scretch

```
it("All errors writted inside", () => {
      const errors = ['e1','e2','e3'];

      cy.wrap(errors).each(er => {
        cy.get('div.el-form-item__error').contains(er)
      });
    });
```

as i understood you need to match all 3 errors in one message